# Use VBA to Open A Folder And Sort By Date Modified?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use:

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & str_folder, vbNormalFocus)
```

to open a folder but would like to add some extra code to make this open but already listed in date modified with most recent at top?

Comment: Change it once in that folder (manually) and Windows will remember it next time you open the folder. Actually there is no [command line switch](https://winaero.com/blog/file-explorer-command-line-arguments-in-windows-10/) for that.

Comment: Thank PeH, the settings within the RDS do not allow for windows to remember this after a user has logged out and we are talking about 100s of different folders this is based on.  Unfortunately not the answer I was hoping for!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can use `SendKeys` to send `Alt`, `A`, `O`, `Arrow Down` and `Enter` (one after another, not together) to the Explorer window to change the view (no idea how reliable this will work). The combination should work for Windows 10 (other versions might need another combination).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this could work (tested in Windows 10). But as usual the [SendKeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) only simulates key strokes and therefore is not a very reliable method.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenExplorerSortByDate()
    Const str_folder As String = "c:\"

    Shell "explorer.exe " & str_folder, vbNormalFocus

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

    SendKeys "%"
    SendKeys "A"
    SendKeys "O"
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```